# Google Places For Android: Attribution Missing Resource

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have an android project that uses the Google Places for Android API. It states that I must accompany my AutoCompleteTextView with a Powered By Google Attribution. However, the @drawable/powered_by_google_* resources do not exist in my project despite having google play services included with gradle.

Where do I get this resource image, I can't even find it online.

Comment: What version of Play Services do you have?

Comment: Pretty sure the latest, using this:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Comment: Try importing places library through this: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0` and see if it includes the drawable image. Alternatively, update to 7.8 released today. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/google-play-services-78-lets-see-whats.html.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has this issue, including the specific libraries I needed as suggested here did correct the issue.